# Can I attach my Pioneer radios "remote control" wire (blue,white) to both the Power antenna and Amp Turn On wires of the harness (Maestro)

Tags: audio

My Pioneer aftermarket radio has a Blue/white wire labelled "remote control" I have read that I can connect this to either the Power antenna wire, or the amp turn on wire.

Is there a way I can connect it to both?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can just crimp everything together, or run the blue remote wire to a distribution block, and then run wires from that to each device (amp, power antenna, etc).

I'm running 2 amps, 1 crossover, and a powered antenna off my Kenwood remote wire.

Answer (score 1):

That would be an affirmative. When I bought the Pioneer for my wife's Hyundai Azera, that is how I attached it to tell both the Alpine amp and electronic antenna to turn on. It's how Crutchfield showed it to be installed for my application. You shouldn't have an issue.